# Redis-node RPOPLPUSH method

Tags: node.js, list, redis, command

I'm using the great **redis-node** library and i have a problem right now:

I have an initial list (**initStockListKey**) created, and the keyname for another list not created yet (**inProgressListKey**), using rpoplpush command

I try to pop from **initStockListKey** and push into **inProgressListKey**, and when verify the list types, i get ***String*** type for the one that was created on the fly.

```
client.rpoplpush(initStockListKey, inProgressListKey, function (err, item)
```

Can you give me an example of how to do that? As far as know, we can't create an empty list on **Redis**.

Comment: When you say that the destination list isn't created and you find that it's a string key, how are you checking this?

Comment: I'm running the following script:    `client.type(inProgressListKey, function (err, type) {                    
                    console.log('type %s', type); 
                });`

Comment: Have you tried to run `type` command in `redis-cli`? Maybe this is a bug in the library but not in Redis...

Comment: Yes, I think so,  i'm getting type string in redis-cli, probably be a library bug